# TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable Как это исправить?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

display_width = 800
display_height = 600

display = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width, display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Run Dinosaur! Run!")

icon = pygame.image.load('icon.png')
pygame.display.set_icon(icon)

user_width = 60
user_height = 100
user_x = display_width // 4
user_y = display_height - user_height - 100

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

make_jump = False
jump_counter = 30


def run_game():
    global make_jump
    game = True

    while game:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                quit()

        key = pygame.key.get_pressed()
        if key(pygame.K_SPACE):
            make_jump = True

            if make_jump == True:
                jump()

        display.fill((255, 255, 255))

        pygame.draw.rect(display, (247, 240, 22), (user_x, user_y, user_width, user_height))

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)


def jump():
    global user_y, jump_counter, make_jump
    if jump_counter >= -30 / 2.5:
        jump_counter -= 1
    else:
        jump_counter = 30
        make_jump = False


run_game()
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/UserSoft/PycharmProjects/dinogame/dinogame.py", line 59, in <module>
    run_game();
  File "C:/Users/UserSoft/PycharmProjects/dinogame/dinogame.py", line 36, in run_game
    if key(pygame.K_SPACE):
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

Comment: напишите текст ошибки целиком

Comment: Без полного трейсбэка не понятно, в каком именно месте у вас возникает ошибка и в чем она заключается. Лучше всего добавить весь вывод консоли в текст вопроса.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Сравнение делается так:

```
if key == pygame.K_SPACE:
```

Вместо этого

```
if make_jump == True:
```

достаточно просто

```
if make_jump:
```